# Select at boot time, from Grub, Nouveau or Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, nouveau

I have a laptop MSI GS60 6QE; CPU is Skylake I7-6700HQ and GPU NVIDIA GTX 970.
I had installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it and is working quiet good.
I've installed NVIDIA 364.19 driver from ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu
I'm using Prime to select the graphic card.
I noticed that when I using this configuration, over the Nouveau driver, the battery life is very short (about 1h 30mins)
If I using Nouveau the battery life is better (about 2:30 to 3 h).
My question is that I can configure Ubuntu to select at boot time, from Grub, which driver to use NVIDIA or Nouveau?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Gabriel

Comment: I can do it with btrfs snapshots easy enough.

Comment: @Pilot6 Could you please answer this with btrfs snapshots? I know nearly nothing about btrfs , let alone btrfs snapshots!

Comment: With or without? With btrfs snapshots it is very easy. It is much more complicated without.

Comment: @Pilot6 what it is btrfs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use kernel parameters to blacklist the driver you don't want to use and force the other one.

```
modprobe.blacklist=nvidia systemd.setenv=GPUMOD=nouveau
```

Plus a script to modify xorg config.

```
cat > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-nv.conf << EOF
Section "Device"
  Identifier   "Device0"
  Driver       "nouveau"
EndSection
EOF
```

[Switching nouveau and nvidia drivers using a single kernel and systemd](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nouveau_%26_nvidia-drivers_switching#Switching_using_a_single_kernel_and_systemd)