# Set graphics driver to nouveau for specific grub menuentry

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, kernel, nouveau

I installed a [patched real-time kernel](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.6/) next to my regular ubuntu 20.04 kernel (the steps I use patching the kernel can be found [here](https://github.com/frankaemika/libfranka/issues/62#issuecomment-844970384)). Now since Nvidia doesn't offer good support for real-time kernels (see [this forum post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/simply-impossible-to-use-an-nvidia-card-on-a-real-time-kernel-no-musician-can-use-nvidia/34947/8)), every time I want to use the real-time kernel, I have to switch back to the Nouveau graphics drivers. As this process takes some time, I wondered if it is possible to specify which graphics driver a kernel uses directly in the kernel load options that are specified in the grub menu item of this kernel. I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/901000/822484) which explains that I can add the following kernel parameters to blacklist the NVidia drivers:

```
modprobe.blacklist=nvidia systemd.setenv=GPUMOD=nouveau
```

This, however, does not seem to work on my system and the real-time kernel still fails to boot (boots with a black screen) unless in the default kernel I change back to using the nouveau drivers (I do this using the software & updates > Additional drivers menu). I searched the web for a solution to my problem but every solution points to the solution given in this [post](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nouveau_%26_nvidia-drivers_switching). I, therefore, suspect something else might go wrong. If somebody has solved this problem on their system and could share their solution or point me in the right direction that would be great.

### What I already tried

I also tried adding the following kernel parameters to my real-time kernel grub menu item:

```
rd.driver.blacklist=nvidia nouveau.modeset=1 nvidia.modeset=0
```

### System information

- **OS:** Ubuntu 20.04
- **PC:** HP Zbook G5 Studio x360
- **RAM:** 2x32 GB Samsung M471A4G43MB1-CTD geheugenmodule 32 GB DDR4 2666 MHz
- **GPU:** Nvidia Quadro P1000
- **CPU:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
- **Default kernel:** 5.8.0-53-generic
- **Realtime kernel:** 5.6.19-rt

### Grub menu items

#### Default kernel

```
    recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  a17c2e53-dd84-48ff-af5e-bd3042e7d38f
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a17c2e53-dd84-48ff-af5e-bd3042e7d38f
fi
echo    'Loading Linux 5.8.0-53-generic ...'
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-53-generic root=UUID=a17c2e53-dd84-48ff-af5e-bd3042e7d38f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-53-generic
```

#### Real-time kernel

```
    recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  a17c2e53-dd84-48ff-af5e-bd3042e7d38f
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a17c2e53-dd84-48ff-af5e-bd3042e7d38f
fi
echo    'Loading Linux 5.6.19-rt12 ...'
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.6.19-rt12 root=UUID=a17c2e53-dd84-48ff-af5e-bd3042e7d38f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff modprobe.blacklist=nvidia systemd.setenv=GPUMOD=nouveau
echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.6.19-rt12
```

Comment: It may not be enough to blacklist nvidia.  Can you try blacklisting nvidia_modeset ?  Also, you may need to remove noveau from the blacklist somewhere in /lib/modprobe.d/ and add it as a blacklist in the kernel command line for your nvidia grub entry.

Comment: @user10489 Thanks a lot! I was unaware that the Nvidia deb also puts blacklist statements inside the `/lib/modprobe.d/` directory. After removing the nouveau blacklist items in this folder and adding `modprobe.blacklist=nvidia systemd.setenv=GPUMOD=nouveau rd.driver.blacklist=nvidia nouveau.modeset=1 nvidia.modeset=0` to the realtime kernels and `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau systemd.setenv=GPUMOD=nvidia rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau nouveau.modeset=0 nvidia.modeset=1` to the regular kernels, the system would boot with the right driver. Please convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not enough to blacklist the nvidia driver on the kernel command line, you also have to remove the nouveau blacklist from files in `/lib/modprobe.d/`.

After removing the blacklists there, you can adjust grub entries that they load the desired driver and blacklist the other driver for both modprobe and the initrd.

To load the nouveau driver:

```
modprobe.blacklist=nvidia systemd.setenv=GPUMOD=nouveau rd.driver.blacklist=nvidia nouveau.modeset=1 nvidia.modeset=0
```

To load the nvidia driver:

```
modprobe.blacklist=nouveau systemd.setenv=GPUMOD=nvidia rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau nouveau.modeset=0 nvidia.modeset=1
```

Comment: When I blacklisted nouveau in `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf` by commenting out nouveau and lbm-nouveau, my system went down after reboot. I got the message flooding my screen NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).

Comment: That sounds backwards. You comment it out to *un*blacklist it.

Comment: I mean I wanted to execute your words "It's not enough to blacklist the nvidia driver on the kernel command line, you also have to remove the nouveau blacklist from files in /lib/modprobe.d/."

Comment: But I havent run the command initramfs -u

Comment: The point of this question is to be able to switch between the two from grub.  My proposed solut9ion is to remove the blacklist from the file and move it to the kernel command line.   That's probably not what you want to do.